# Iterate through xpath? - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, xpath

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[3]/div[3]/div[2]/a[*[local-name()='time']]")
for links in a:
  print (links.text)
```

This is a bit of code for a Project I'm building for Instagram in selenium I'm trying to monitor the last couple post on my timeline to be able to catch the most recent post. This code alone prints the text form of a link on Instagram. The only thing that changes in this code per new post is

```
article[3]
```

was wondering if I there was a way to iterate through the 'article' with a for loop to be able to print in text form the last 5 or 10 posts.

Comment: Is it the case that under `article[3]` there is a bunch of posts and to get the text you want you do the whole `a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[3]/div[3]/div[2]/a[*[local-name()='time']]`? Can you post some example html?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another iterator and use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) to insert the value into your XPath.

```
for index in range(1,10):
    a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//article[{index}]/div[3]/div[2]/a[*[local-name()='time']]")
    for links in a:
        print(links.text)
```